# sqlite3.OperationalError... what is wrong in my sqlite syntax?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

Python 3 + tkinter and sqlite3

I'm doing a mock application to save a piece of text in sqlite

here's the function:

```
 def saveNote(self,note_id):

    conn = db.connect(fname)
    c = conn.cursor()
    safeTitle=self.newNoteTitle.get()
    safeContents=self.newNoteText.get("1.0",tk.END)
    safeLink=self.newNoteLink.get()
    safeRemarks=self.newNoteRemarks.get()
    conn.execute('UPDATE notes SET (title,contents,remarks,link,created,last_modified,notebook_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?) WHERE notes_id=5', (safeTitle, safeContents, safeRemarks, safeLink, 1))
    conn.commit()
        self.master.destroy()
```

When executing the function, I get this error:

```
 conn.execute('UPDATE notes SET (title,contents,remarks,link,created,last_modified,notebook_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?) WHERE notes_id=5', (safeTitle, safeContents, safeRemarks, safeLink, 1))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

I don't quite understand why the syntax is wrong...(I'm new to python)...can anyone help me spot the mistake?

Thanks

Comment: The SQLite syntax diagrams are very helpful: for example, https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html and https://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: Thanks for the link but I've already read it and my syntax seems ok?

Comment: Your syntax is flawed. The word `VALUES` doesn't appear anywhere on this syntax diagram: https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html Neither does `(` or `)`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your SQL statement is correct. From what you explained you are looking to insert data in to your table, so you want to actually use an INSERT statement and not UPDATE. I think you might want to do this instead:

```
INSERT INTO notes(title,contents,remarks,link,created,last_modified,notebook_id)
VALUES(INSERT_THE_VALUES_YOU_WANT_TO_INSERT_HERE)
```

If you are in fact looking to update existing data, then your syntax should look like this:

Just fill in the `""` with the values you want to set

```
UPDATE notes
SET 
title = "",
contents = "",
remarkts = "",
link = "",
created = "",
last_modified = "",
notebook_id = ""
WHERE notes_id=5
```

To remove any confusion with the query I provided, you want to structure your query within your Python like this:

```
conn.execute('UPDATE notes SET title=?,contents=?,remarks=?,link=?,created=?,last_modified=?,notebook_id=?
WHERE notes_id=5', (safeTitle, safeContents, safeRemarks, safeLink, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 1))
```

Comment: I'm actually updating an already existing note..hence why the "hardcoded" note_id (I was trying to debug it)

Comment: Then your update syntax is incorrect. I'll update my answer.

Comment: in that case I would not be using parameters, exposing my code to sql injections!

Comment: I have no idea why you are jumping to sql injections. You are trying to interface to a db. You wrote SQL syntax that was incorrect and you were provided with the correct syntax. If you are worried about SQL injection, then you should write up data sanitization methods to check every input.

Comment: What I mean is...your version is certainly correct, but it's "different", because it doesn't use any parameters. As I understand, the best practice is to parameterize queries to make them secure by default. Also, I would like to learn why that parameterized syntax is wrong instead of using an alternative.... The parameters I got from here: # example 1 -- simple placeholders
db.execute('update players set name=?, score=?, active=? where jerseyNum=?', ('Smith, Steve', 42, True, 99))

Comment: As mentioned in my original post 'Just fill in the "" with the values you want to set' when you modify your code.

Comment: Link was here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parametrized_SQL_statement section python

Comment: Look at the syntax very carefully. The structure for the update statement is how I provided it to you. Yes it is definitely different, because I only provided you with the query structure.

Comment: Thank you for helping, now I see it :)